# How to modify block 0 / UID of a Mifare 1K tag (using a proxmark)

Tags: edit, mifare, uid

I bricked a Mifare 1k tag during an attempt to write to block n°0 (to change the UID), I would like to understand what I did wrong.

Just for reminder, the datasheet of the Mifare 1k => [1](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/6c1b33bd10c9915a2a055db4a850421321d6c2fb/68747470733a2f2f66697265666172742e61742f696d672f6d69666172652f6d69666172655f6d656d6f72795f6c61796f75745f7468756d622e706e67)

I used :

- a Proxmark Easy ;
- a tag with a writable block 0 (bought online).

First, I searched the tag

```
proxmark3> hf search
          
 UID : fa 33 78 19          
ATQA : 00 04          
 SAK : 08 [2]          
TYPE : NXP MIFARE CLASSIC 1k | Plus 2k SL1          
proprietary non iso14443-4 card found, RATS not supported          
No chinese magic backdoor command detected          
Prng detection: WEAK
```

So, the UID is `fa 33 78 19`

Then, I read de block 0 using the key A (which I knew to be "FFFFFFFFFFFF")

```
proxmark3> hf mf rdbl 0 A FFFFFFFFFFFF

--block no:0, key type:A, key:ff ff ff ff ff ff           
#db# READ BLOCK FINISHED          
isOk:01 data:fa 33 78 19 a8 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69
```

We find the UID identified earlier `fa 33 78 19`

Then, I tried to modify it by replacing only the bytes associated to the UID :

```
proxmark3> hf mf wrbl 0 A FFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFa80804006263646566676869
--block no:0, key type:A, key:ff ff ff ff ff ff          
--data: ff ff ff ff a8 08 04 00 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69          
#db# WRITE BLOCK FINISHED          
isOk:01
```

But after that, there's no way to communicate with the tag, it's bricked...

```
proxmark3> hf mf rdbl 0 A FFFFFFFFFFFF
--block no:0, key type:A, key:ff ff ff ff ff ff           
#db# Can't select card          
#db# READ BLOCK FINISHED          
isOk:00  
        
proxmark3> hf search
          
#db# Reading card ...          
No or unknown card found, aborting
```

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution :

The block 0 is composed of: 4 bytes of UID, 1 byte of BCC and 11 other Manufacturer bytes [Datasheet](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Flavio_Garcia/publication/220713937/figure/fig1/AS:393943087894572@1470934759767/Memory-layout-of-the-Mifare-Classic.png)

BCC depends on UID: it's a XOR of four UID bytes.
Writing a bad BCC bricks the tag.

There are several sites that allow the BCC to be calculated from the desired UID : [here](https://nric.biz/mifare-bcc-calculator.html)

Now, the question is: Can we "unbrick" a tag ?

On other forums, some people say they succeeded with their ACR122U (libnfc) but for my part, I own a Proxmark 3 Easy and I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

I found It's a very old topic but It still have some info that may help some one.
You can "unbrick" a tag that "soft-brick" (cause invalid bcc). [Instruction here](https://github.com/RfidResearchGroup/proxmark3/blob/master/doc/magic_cards_notes.md#mifare-classic-directwrite-aka-gen2-aka-cuid)

```
#e.g. for 4b UID:

hf 14a config --atqa force --bcc ignore --cl2 skip --rats skip
hf mf wrbl 0 A FFFFFFFFFFFF 11223344440804006263646566676869 # for 1k
hf mf wrbl 0 A FFFFFFFFFFFF 11223344441802006263646566676869 # for 4k
hf 14a config --std
hf 14a reader
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Also note that this method requires the **RRG / Iceman** firmware.